# Como criar função com tipo de retorno dinâmico?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Ao trabalhar com TypeScript, me deparei com um problema. Possuo uma função que retorna um objeto do tipo `ObjetoComposto<any | any[]>`, mas gostaria de definir o tipo de objeto que será enviado como parâmetro dependendo de como a função for chamada.

O melhor exemplo do que eu quero é com uma função simples de consulta a dados em um servidor usando Angular e `HttpClient`:

```
getData(): Observable<Modelo[]> {
  return this.http.get<Modelo[]>(PATH);
}
```

Onde o tipo `Modelo` é usado para "tipar" os dados do Observable que será enviado como retorno. Se isso não for passado, o TypeScript interpretará o `Observable` como `Observable<unkown>`, ou `Observable<any>`, dependendo o pacote de autocomplete recebido.

Em suma, eu quero poder passar meu objeto `Modelo` dentro de `ObjetoComposto` ao chamar a função dessa forma:

```
getObjeto(): ObjetoComposto<Modelo>{
  return this.objetoCreator.create<Modelo>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que usar [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

```
getObjeto<T>(): <T>{
  return this.objetoCreator.create();
}

getData<T>(): Observable<T> {
  return this.http.get<T>(PATH);
}
```

Para chamar assim:

```
this.getObjeto<SuaInterfaceOuClasse>();
```